# How to remove the empty rows in the table in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

[image]

Hi all,

I have a table in PowerBI as shown in the screenshot above. I want to remove the rows in the table where column D is empty. So in the example above, the rows that should be removed are row7,8,9,10. In Power Query Editor, I'm only able to remove the rows if the entire row is empty.

May I know how should I remove row 7-10 in PowerBI? In future, if the data for row 7-10 in column D are available, then it will be restored back. Is this possible to achieve? Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The PQ editor allows you to filter on just columns as well. Click the column arrow, then choose "remove empty". The resulting filter is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as @Jeroen Mostert mentioned in his comment, within Power Query, or if you are just trying to display the table as a table visual in Power BI like this...

[image]

...then you could just filter the table visual by the column with blanks within Power BI without doing anything in Power Query.

To filter the table visual:

1. select the table visual
2. then, in the Filters pane, find the section about your column named Final, and then select "is not blank" from the drop-down selection below "Show items when the value"
3. then click Apply filter.

This screen snip shows the table visual selected and the Filters pane visible with "is not blank" selected in its drop-down.

[image]

Comment: The question so nice you answered it twice! (Or, more likely, a network hiccup, but one of these should be deleted.)

Comment: I know what happened. I meant to submit a minor cosmetic edit to my answer, but posted a second response instead. Oops!